# conditional statements to only accept integer as an input Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, conditional-statements

I wrote a code where it asks multiple individuals questions, and every individuals' response is put into a hash. This is in a loop and looks something like this

```
arr:[]
     (1..n).each do |i|

 hash=Hash.new()

 puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}" 
 hash["day1"]=gets.chomp.to_f

 puts "Please input a value for day # #{i}" 
 hash["day2"]=gets.chomp.to_f

 arr << hash
 end
```

So to avoid any incorrect input (i.e. entering string instead of an integer/number), I need to place a conditional statement. 
I am super lost with how I would do that though since I am assigning the users' input into a hash at the same time I take their input. 
Is it even possible to do that or should I take a different route completely.

thanks

Comment: What you want here is `hash["day1"]= Integer(gets) rescue nil`

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question, but it sounds like your asking how can you access the values entered in the hash? After the key gets assigned the user input, you can re-access it by the same key, like `if hash["day1"] == 'some_value'`.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Your code won't run because of errors.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can get day values like below. When a character other than a number is entered, it asks the value of that day again.

```
puts 'Enter number of days'
days_hash = {}
number_of_days = gets.chomp.to_i
day = 1

while day <= number_of_days
  puts "Please enter a value for day # #{day}" 
  input = gets.chomp
  if input !~ /\D/
    days_hash["day#{day}"] = input.to_i
    day += 1
  else
    puts "Please enter only number"
    next
  end
end

p days_hash
#=> { "day1" => 2, "day2" => 4, "day3" => 8 }
days_hash['day2']
#=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider this general approach for validating user input, **note that this example** `require 'date'`.

So, you can check user input to be an integer or a float or a formatted date or anything you could add...

---

First define an array of questions containing the question text, validation method and way to convert the input, like this:

```
questions = [
              {text: "Enter an integer:", validate: :must_be_an_integer, convert: :my_to_i},
              {text: "Enter a float:", validate: :must_be_a_float, convert: :my_to_f},
              {text: "Enter a data as d-m-yyyy", validate: :must_be_a_formatted_date, convert: :to_formatted_date}
             ]
```

---

Then define some methods to be called by `:validate` key, for user input validation:

```
def must_be_an_integer(num)
  Integer(num).class == Integer rescue false
end

def must_be_a_float(num)
  Float(num).class == Float && num.include?('.') rescue false
end

def must_be_a_formatted_date(date_str)
  date = Date.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%Y") rescue false
  return false unless date
  date.year <= 9999 && date.year >= 1000
end
```

---

Define also the methods required by the key `:convert` (need to pass an argument, that's why `my_to_i` and `my_to_f`):

```
def my_to_i(num)
  num.to_i
end

def my_to_f(num)
  num.to_f
end

def to_formatted_date(date_str)
  DateTime.strptime(date_str, "%d-%m-%y")
end
```

---

Finally iterate over the questions:

```
res = questions.map do |question|
  answer = nil
  3.times do
    puts question[:text]
    u_input = gets.chomp
    if send question[:validate], u_input
      answer = send question[:convert], u_input
      break
    end
  end
  if answer.nil?
    puts "C'mon man! Check your keyboard!" # after three input errors!!
    break
  end
  { question: question[:text], answer: answer }
end
```

---

Example of a result:

```
#=> [
     {:question=>"Enter an integer:", :answer=>1},
     {:question=>"Enter a float:", :answer=>1.1},
     {:question=>"Enter a data as d-m-Y", :answer=>#<DateTime: 2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459150j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}
    ]
```